# Door sticking, frame no longer square, is this serious?

Tags: foundation, door-frame

I'm a rookie home owner. My "mudroom" door (never heard that term before this house) has started to stick. The house was built in 1952. At the time it was just the house, and the garage and mudroom were both additions. There is no access under either the mudroom or the garage.

Checking it recently, I notice:

- The gaps on the side and tops of the door are now inconsistent from side to side, top to bottom. Door is definitely askew in the frame.
- The top of the door frame is no longer truly straight, but bowed slightly
- In the wood that forms the area around the window to the right of the door, there is a hairline gap between the planks that appears to be bigger than any on the other side.
- Above the door, there is a hairline gap between the vertical and horizontal joint.

It's hard to check level, since both the top and the bottom of the door frame are bowed slightly.

My questions, knowing I can only give a rough description:

1. Is this common, or should I be worried?
2. What's the ballpark cost (cost ranges) to set this right?
3. Who would be qualified to check this out? A home inspector? Is it serious enough for a structural engineer?

Pics, inside:
[Top of Door, showing uneven gaps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6f7of.jpg)
[Just to right of door, showing crack above and split betweeen panels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8bdx.jpg)
[Bottom of door, showing uneven gaps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZh8l.jpg)

Pics, outside:
[Base of door, showing crack in block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtBkD.jpg)
[Left of door, showing minor crack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ws3aL.jpg)
[Right of door, showing bigger crack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2Oa6.jpg)

Comment: This could be a relatively minor thing (e.g. one of your hinges got loosened or bent) or it could be a symptom of some structural problems. Can you add some photos of the door/window and some background info (age of house, has any work been done recently that might affect this, etc.)?

Comment: Has it gotten much worse in a short period of time,say a few months or gradual over a year?

Comment: Age of house?  Termites?  Pictures?  Period of time over which this changed?  Anything loose?  Is the door itself a true rectangle (equal measurements on sides?)

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/839/how-can-i-fix-a-door-that-doesnt-close-because-it-doesnt-fit-the-frame?rq=1

Comment: @mikes seems to have gotten worse over the year we've owned it, we thought it was weather related, but doesn't seem so.

Comment: @ShimonRura photos added, and no work done recently

Comment: Was this house inspected before you bought it?  If not, get one now.  There should at least be some sort of crawl space between the ground and the structure.  I'd be worried that it does not have a proper foundation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like you have a structural problem in the front wall or foundation of the mudroom. This is evidenced by the [severe cracking in the brick to the right of the door](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE6Wu.jpg), as well as cracking in the concrete [under your threshold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsAsf.jpg) and [at left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5xBZ.jpg). The picture showing cracking to the right of your door also shows more mortar above the lowest course of bricks than in between the other courses; this suggests that this problem was patched before, but has recently gotten worse.

Considering that, it is likely that structural repairs will be needed. These could be incremental fixes, reinforcing some weak parts, or a more comprehensive fix (such as replacing the mud room's foundation or footings) could be required. Furthermore, if the failure occurred because of water/drainage problems, you will want to take corrective action there to ensure it doesn't happen again.

I would recommend you call some experienced masons and general builders to assess the situation. Because the mudroom is its own addition, the worst-case scenario is that the whole addition has to be rebuilt. More likely is that some significant foundation and masonry repairs are needed, somewhere in the $1000-3000 range. Once that's done you can do the door/carpentry fixes.

Note that this can be a complex issue to diagnose in person, let alone from pictures over the internet. You'll want to get several opinions from people who know what they're doing. A structural engineer may not be necessary, but their opinion could help you distinguish between the builders who understand what's going on and the ones who just want to sell you an overpriced patch.

Answer (score 2):

Doors sticking and cracks on outer brick work = you need some piering work! This is pretty pricing, but unfortunately the only permanent solution.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming!

Answer (score 1):

First, get a good square and level and check exactly what is out of line.  Also check the floor in the area.  Look in the basement at the support beams.  Are they sagging?  Have they been modified from the original plan with some sort of renovation?  In other words, **make sure this is not a symptom of some bigger problem.**

If it's a new house, they settle and these things will happen.  In another month or year it may correct itself.  Some move in cycles with the seasons.  If it's small, don't worry about it.

If simply sanding a bit off the top/bottom to make it stop sticking is not sufficient, you can remove the trim, pull out the entire door jamb (it sits within the supporting structure) and replace it with a new one that is square.  Then **seal/insulate it properly**, put up new trim, paint, and you're done.

Comment: Thanks Brian, answer edited based on your questions. House from 1952, an addition, so no beams under to check it.